# jQuery selector speed performation

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

I have a big table list of products, which is dynamic and changes with ajax. There is a for about 100 rows in that table.

I saw already that a contextual method `$('.className', '#parentElement');` of selecting elements performs much better than usual `$('.className');` or `$('#parentElement .className');`. (correct me if wrong)

In some circumstances i need to select a specific element with jQuery, there are dynamically added unique `id="product-name-123456"` and `class="mainproductOffer"` to each new row.

**So, what performs faster from these two methods ?**

1. `$('tr[id^=product-name-]').click(function(){...});`
2. `$('tr.mainproductOffer').click(function(){...});`

or

Is there any other method doing the same thing faster ?

Comment: In this case use the class selector and event delegation (for example: $('table').on('click','tr.mainproductOffer',function() {});

Comment: Actually this combination `$('.mainproductOffer').on("click", handler)` (jQuery v1.7+) will perform faster since `click()` is a shortcut, which will execute `on("click")` (or `bind("click")`) anyways.

Comment: What I do not seem to understand in this question is, why don't you populate real data, and then just test it to see which performs better? Not forgetting to mention [jsPerf](http://jsperf.com/)

Comment: @axel.michel : you should post your comment as answer and the OP should accept it. You were the first and people here are just repeating as your comment ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case use the class selector, it is faster than the attribut selector. 
You should use event delegation - for example:

```
$('table').on('click','.mainproductOffer',function() {});
```

to reduce the number of event handlers. If the class (mainproductOffer) is only used for the TR tag, remove the Tag from the selector too.

Comment: thank you for your answer. pls can u tell me if it will behave with `div` or `ul li` the same way as with table ? for example: `$("ul").on("click", ".somethingUnderListItem");` ? thank u

Comment: @aspirinemaga yes, you can use the delegation on all these elements, but your basic element / selector should be as appropriate as possible,  a DIV or UL might be a bit to global.

Answer (score 1):

> So, what performs faster from these two methods ?

$('tr.mainproductOffer').click(function(){...});

> Is there any other method doing the same thing faster ?

Unsurpassed article '[jQuery Anti-Patterns for Performance](http://paulirish.com/2009/perf/)' would help you

Comment: It’s even faster to remove the `tr` from the selector, `$('.mainproductOffer')`

Comment: This is true, but it was not among the options proposed by the author. I've just a straight answered to the question :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Use on() (event delegation), since its dynamically added.
2. Class selector is faster than attribute selector

   `$('tr').on( 'click', '.mainproductOffer', function(){...});`

Comment: this is not actually delegating since `.mainproductOffer` is the selector of the `tr` tag ... you should actually target the parent, which is `table` as pointed ou by @axel.michel in his comment.

Comment: He is not adding new tr to the table. He is adding dynamic controls to each new row.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('tr.mainproductOffer').click(function(){.....; OR
$('table').on( 'click', 'tr.mainproductOffer', function(){...;
```

are faster since

according to the jquery [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

> jQuery can process simple selectors of the form tag#id.class very quickly when they are used to filter delegated events. So, "#myForm", "a.external", and "button" are all fast selectors. Delegated events that use more complex selectors, particularly hierarchical ones, can be several times slower--although they are still fast enough for most applications. **Hierarchical selectors can often be avoided simply by attaching the handler to a more appropriate point in the document**. For example, instead of **$("body").on("click", "#commentForm .addNew", addComment)** use **$("#commentForm").on("click", ".addNew", addComment)**.

Comment: this is redundant since `.mainproductOffer` is the selector of the `tr` tag ... if you want event delegation, you should actually target the parent, which is `table` as pointed ou by @axel.michel in his comment